# Unit tests for collisions

Tags: unit-testing, collision, actionscript-3

I'm finding it a bit tedious to write unit tests for my collision class because there are so many variations of collisions that need testing.  I see repetition in the set-up and assertion stages of each test, but I don't see how I can reduce the repetition whilst keeping the code clear and concise.

```
package tests.kris {
  import asunitsrc.asunit.framework.TestCase;
  import flash.geom.Rectangle;
  import kris.RectangleCollision;
  public class RectangleCollisionTest extends TestCase {
    public function RectangleCollisionTest(testMethod:String):void {
      super(testMethod);
    }

    // detect
    public function detect_should_throw_error_when_both_arguments_are_the_same_object():void {
      var callOn:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
      assertThrowsError(RectangleCollision.detect, callOn, callOn);
    }

    public function calling_detect_on_intersecting_rectangles_should_return_true():void {
      var callOn:Rectangle = new Rectangle(1, 1, 5, 5);
      var callWith:Rectangle = new Rectangle(2, 2, 5, 5);
      assertTrue(areColliding(callOn, callWith));
    }

    public function calling_detect_on_rectangles_with_a_touching_side_should_return_false():void {
      var callOn:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 5, 5);
      var callWith:Rectangle = new Rectangle(5, 0, 5, 5);
      assertFalse(areColliding(callOn, callWith));
    }

    // Currently only works with rectangles that are rougly the same size and have shallow collisions

    // resolve
    public function calling_resolve_should_throw_error_when_both_arguments_are_the_same_object():void {
      var reactionary:Rectangle = newRectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
      assertThrowsError(RectangleCollision.resolve, reactionary, reactionary);
    }

    public function calling_reslove_on_not_colliding_rectangles_returns_reactionary():void {
      var reactionary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
      var stationary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 100);
      var result:Rectangle = RectangleCollision.resolve(reactionary, stationary);
      assertPosition(reactionary, 0, 0);
      assertPosition(stationary, 200, 200);
      assertPosition(result, 0, 0);
    }

    public function should_reslove_to_left_correctly_1():void {
      var reactionary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(2, 1, 100, 100);
      var stationary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(100, 0, 100, 100);
      var result:Rectangle = RectangleCollision.resolve(reactionary, stationary);
      assertPosition(reactionary, 2, 1);
      assertPosition(stationary, 100, 0);
      assertPosition(result, 0, 1);
    }

    public function should_reslove_to_left_correctly_2():void {
      var reactionary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(2, -1, 100, 100);
      var stationary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(100, 0, 100, 100);
      var result:Rectangle = RectangleCollision.resolve(reactionary, stationary);
      assertPosition(reactionary, 2, -1);
      assertPosition(stationary, 100, 0);
      assertPosition(result, 0, -1);
    }

    public function should_reslove_to_right_correctly_1():void {
      var reactionary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(98, 1, 100, 100);
      var stationary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
      var result:Rectangle = RectangleCollision.resolve(reactionary, stationary);
      assertPosition(reactionary, 98, 1);
      assertPosition(stationary, 0, 0);
      assertPosition(result, 100, 1);
    }

    public function should_reslove_to_right_correctly_2():void {
      var reactionary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(98, -1, 100, 100);
      var stationary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
      var result:Rectangle = RectangleCollision.resolve(reactionary, stationary);
      assertPosition(reactionary, 98, -1);
      assertPosition(stationary, 0, 0);
      assertPosition(result, 100, -1);
    }

    public function should_reslove_to_top_correctly_1():void {
      var reactionary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(1, 2, 100, 100);
      var stationary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 100, 100, 100);
      var result:Rectangle = RectangleCollision.resolve(reactionary, stationary);
      assertPosition(reactionary, 1, 2);
      assertPosition(stationary, 0, 100);
      assertPosition(result, 1, 0);
    }

    public function should_reslove_to_top_correctly_2():void {
      var reactionary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(-1, 2, 100, 100);
      var stationary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 100, 100, 100);
      var result:Rectangle = RectangleCollision.resolve(reactionary, stationary);
      assertPosition(reactionary, -1, 2);
      assertPosition(stationary, 0, 100);
      assertPosition(result, -1, 0);
    }

    public function should_reslove_to_bottom_correctly_1():void {
      var reactionary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(1, 98, 100, 100);
      var stationary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
      var result:Rectangle = RectangleCollision.resolve(reactionary, stationary);
      assertPosition(reactionary, 1, 98);
      assertPosition(stationary, 0, 0);
      assertPosition(result, 1, 100);
    }

    public function should_reslove_to_bottom_correctly_2():void {
      var reactionary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(-1, 98, 100, 100);
      var stationary:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
      var result:Rectangle = RectangleCollision.resolve(reactionary, stationary);
      assertPosition(reactionary, -1, 98);
      assertPosition(stationary, 0, 0);
      assertPosition(result, -1, 100);
    }

    private function assertPosition(rect:Rectangle, x:Number, y:Number):void {
      assertEquals(x, rect.x);
      assertEquals(y, rect.y);
    }

    private function assertThrowsError(... args):void {
      assertTrue(functionThrowsError.apply(null, args));
    }

    private function functionThrowsError(functionToCall:Function, ... args):Boolean {
      try {
          functionToCall.apply(null, args);
          return false;
      } catch (error:Error) {
          return true;
      }
      throw new Error("Should not reach this point");
    }

    private function newRectangle(x:Number = 0, y:Number = 0, w:Number = 0, h:Number = 0):Rectangle {
      return new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
    }

    private function areColliding(rectangle1:Rectangle, rectangle2:Rectangle):Boolean {
      return RectangleCollision.detect(rectangle1, rectangle2);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's best practice, but you could set up the needed Rectangles/Positions/expected Intersections in the setup method, so that the tests itselfs are shorter and faster to understand.

I wrote some intersection unit tests myself the last weeks, i know that sometime you'll get confused about what the test ought to do.

Also, you should maybe check for degenerate cases, i.e. a rectangle with zero width and/or height.

Comment: i would do, but i have to pass the function different arguments each time, so i can't put it in the setUp method. i know these don't test the edge cases enough, i wanted to ask if there was a way to relieve the repetition before i tested it more.

Comment: Why are you asserting the positions of the input rectangles in every test? Can they be modified by the collision tests?                                                      If so, you could extract a method for the repeating creation of rectangles and testing it by making an array with input and expected positions/intersection points.

Comment: No they can't, I put those there to test that they had not moved. If I make a modification later and that modification changes the position of one of the inputs it will fail the test and I will know I have introduced a bug.